# Images are too small on handheld devices and change proportions

Tags: html, helpndoc

I have developed this help system with HelpNDoc but I don’t understand why images end up small and distorted if displayed on a resized browser window on a PC. Link:

http://trucklesoft.co.uk/help/BriefOverview.html#Languages

On small devices like iPad:

[image: ipad]

My legacy help system which was not created using HelpNDoc:

[image: legacy help]

Legacy link:

https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/msa/helponline/source/helpoptionsbriefoverview.htm

## Update

Here is the HelpNDoc own help system:

https://www.helpndoc.com/sites/default/files/documentation/html/Styleseditor.html

Their images are scaling correctly! Their `max-width` is set to `100%` so that can't be the reason.

## Update 2

I seemed to have manually fixed it - look here:

http://trucklesoft.co.uk/help/Authorization.html

All I have done is remove the image widths and heights. Then it flows nicely.

Comment: There is no size in pixel or percent set for image and its parent `<TD>`. are you looking for a fixed percent of document width or fixed size for image?

Comment: Using the console DevTools I saw that your problem seems to be: `#topic-content img {
    max-width: 100%;
}` Try to remove it.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour The key is things remain readable.

Comment: @Fabio_MO Thanks. I will investigate. I know I can add custom CSS to the software that builds the help system, but I don’t know about removing. Could we set it as an alternative value instead?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour I added link to legacy site for comparison.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Try for example to set `max-width: fit-content;` in css but I sauggest you to check the DevTools and try to set dinamically the style for understanding the bahaviour before write the code

Comment: @Fabio_MO I tried your suggestion. Whilst it made the image larger, overall the effect on the site was negative. I like how the topics current fit the browser properly, like on iPad. If I change the setting as stated the experience is more unpleasant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your content has changed since you asked the question but from your screenshot, it looks like the image was placed in a table cell. And its CSS rule indicates that it must have a `max-width: 100%` meaning that it must fit in its container, no matter its width. If the table cell is resized on a smaller screen, so is the image it contains: that's what is causing the problem.

To fix this, you have multiple options:

1. Force the table cell to be always a specific size, even on smaller devices:

   - Right click on the cell in HelpNDoc's topic editor
   - Click "Table properties"
   - In the "Cells" tab, choose a "Preferred width" in pixels
2. Remove the `max-width: 100%` for this image or all images:

   - Click the top part of the "Generate Help" button in HelpNDoc's "Home" ribbon tab
   - Select your HTML build
   - Click "Customize"
   - In the "Template settings" tab, locate the "Custom CSS" item
   - Add a custom CSS code such as `#topic-content img {max-width: none}`

Then make sure that you generate your HTML documentation again.

Comment: Thanks. At the moment I just reset all images so that they did not have a dimension specified in the HTML code. Also, it seems that if you have a cell with just an image and then a cell with text that it always shows not well. So I reorganized how I displayed content.

You mentioned about removing the `max-width` for "this image" as opposed to all. How would you do that?

Comment: This can be done by targeting specific images via CSS rules. Such as `table img {max-width: none}` for images within tables...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using viewport height and viewport widht will solve the problem.
Try that out!

Comment: Thanks, however this should really be a comment rather than an answer I think.

Comment: Well....Andrew, I couldn't comment because my reputation was too low.In the future I will keep your suggestion in mind!

Answer (score 0):

As you have set a map on the image, and the maps are not responsive, you need to use fixed size for image (198px) however bootstrap sets `max-width:100%` on all children elements. So if you have a `<td>` with small sizes, the image will also resize to its parent 100% width. The conclusion is to set a fixed size for `<td>` and `width:100%` for image itself:

```
    <td valign="middle" style="padding: 10px;width:198px;">
       <p class="rvps4">
         <img alt="" style="padding:1px; width:100%" src="lib/MAP_MNU_Options.png" usemap="#57DA0D7BD5934A4491D380D9F8AD74BD">
       </p>
    </td>
```

Comment: Thanks. Will look. I am confused because I set that map up. Will investigate. However please note all pages with images have issues. Not just in tables.